# Mapping through data and creating input fields, but why can I type in all of them except one?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

There is a section of my "Publish" page called "Metadata" which is a component that receives info from an API and populates only one row of inputs with that API info.

However, I can also add rows to that section which are empty inputs. For some reason, I can type in those inputs, but I cannot modify the inputs that contain the API info, even though I have an onChange handler for all of them.

I've tried a million different things. It's getting so complicated for me to even look at this and try to explain what I've done...

Publish page

```js
<section id="publish-section-10">
 {this.state.showRows  ? <Metadata rowInfo={this.state.insightDetails}/> : 
   null}
</section>
```

Metadata/ component

```js
export default class Metadata extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      numberOfRows: []
    };

    this.addNewRow = this.addNewRow.bind(this);
    this.deleteRow = this.deleteRow.bind(this);
  }

  addNewRow() {
    this.setState({
      numberOfRows: [
        ...this.state.numberOfRows,

        { dbname: "", portno: "", servername: "", tablenames: "" }
      ]
    });
  }

  deleteRow(index) {
    let arr = [...this.state.numberOfRows];
    arr.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState({
      numberOfRows: [...arr]
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.rowInfo !== this.props.rowInfo) {
      this.setState({
        numberOfRows: [...this.state.numberOfRows, ...[nextProps.rowInfo]]
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      numberOfRows: [this.props.rowInfo]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="Grid">
          <div class="Col Col--12">
            <div class="grid-block">
              <button
                onClick={this.addNewRow}
                className="Button--secondary float-right"
              >
                Add Row
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.numberOfRows[0] ? (
          this.state.numberOfRows.map((row, i) => (
            <MetaRow row={row} index={i} onClickX={() => this.deleteRow(i)} />
          ))
        ) : (
          <MetaRow row={{}} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MetaRow component -- this is the component with the inputs that are only letting me type in them if they're empty. I can't type in them when they are populated with API data.

```js
export default class MetaRow extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        serverName: '',
        portNo: '',
        dbName: '',
        tableNames: ''
      }

      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { row, index } = this.props;

        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <section id="publish-section-11">
                {index && index > 0 ? <hr className="top-hr-row" /> : null}
                <div class="Grid">
                  <div class="Col Col--2">
                    <div class="grid-block">
                      <div class="Form-group">
                        <label class="Form-label">
                          Server Name <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="serverName"
                          type="text"
                          class="Form-input metadata-input"
                          value={row[0] ? row[0].servername : this.state.serverName}
                          placeholder={row[0] ? row[0].servername : "Data Source Server"}
                          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="colon">:</div>
                  <div class="Col Col--2">
                    <div class="grid-block">
                      <div class="Form-group">
                        <label class="Form-label">
                          Port Number <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="portNo"
                          type="text"
                          class="Form-input metadata-input"
                          value={row[0] ? row[0].portno : this.state.portNo}
                          placeholder={row[0] ? row[0].portno : "Port Number for Server"}
                          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Col Col--3">
                    <div class="grid-block">
                      <div class="Form-group">
                        <label class="Form-label">
                          Database Name <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="dbName"
                          type="text"
                          class="Form-input metadata-input"
                          value={row[0] ? row[0].dbname : this.state.dbName}
                          placeholder={row[0] ? row[0].dbname : "Database Name"}
                          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Col Col--3">
                    <div class="grid-block">
                      <div class="Form-group">
                        <label class="Form-label">
                          Table Name(s) <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="tableNames"
                          type="text"
                          class="Form-input metadata-input"
                          value={row[0] ? row[0].tablenames : this.state.tableNames}
                          placeholder={row[0] ? row[0].tablenames : "Table Names (Comma separated values)"}
                          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {index && index > 0 ?    
                  <div className="delete-row">
                    <span onClick={this.props.onClickX}>
                      <i className="Icon Icon--close"></i>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                    : null}
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ignore this if I'm too late. I think what might be happening is, inside the MetaRow component, the value of row[0] is populated (since you're passing in the api information), so on each render it's taking the value of row[0].[key] (which is static) instead of the changing state value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `defaultValue` instead of `value` the input like this.

```
<input
 id="dbName"
 type="text"
 class="Form-input metadata-input"
 defaultValue={row[0] ? row[0].dbname : this.state.dbName}
 placeholder={row[0] ? row[0].dbname : "Database Name"}
 onChange={this.handleInputChange}
 />
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I really thought this was going to work because I forgot to add this and had it in other parts of my app, but for some reason it's still not working  :/